# Apache MyFaces Trinidad 1.2 throws NullPointerException with Tomcat 8.5

Tags: trinidad

I created a JSF 1.2 project in eclipse and deployed on Tomcat 8.5 but it throws NullPointerException when I open the jsp page in a browser.

The application works fine in Tomcat 6.
I am using JSF 1.2 and Apache MyFaces Trinidad 1.2

The following is jsp page

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html"
    xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad"
     version="1.2">
    <jsp:directive.page language="java"
        contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" />
    <jsp:text>
        <![CDATA[ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> ]]>
    </jsp:text>
    <jsp:text>
        <![CDATA[ <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ]]>
    </jsp:text>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <f:view>
    <tr:outputText value="test jsf"></tr:outputText>        
    </f:view>
</body>
    </html>
</jsp:root>
```

The following is the exception in console of eclipse

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:113)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperty(UIXComponentELTag.java:135)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.UIXValueTag.setProperties(UIXValueTag.java:77)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.core.output.CoreOutputTextTag.setProperties(CoreOutputTextTag.java:158)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperties(UIXComponentELTag.java:122)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentELTag.createComponent(UIComponentELTag.java:230)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.createChild(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:486)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:670)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.doStartTag(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1142)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.doStartTag(UIXComponentELTag.java:71)
    at org.apache.jsp.NewFile1_jsp._jspx_meth_tr_005foutputText_005f0(NewFile1_jsp.java:211)
    at org.apache.jsp.NewFile1_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(NewFile1_jsp.java:179)
    at org.apache.jsp.NewFile1_jsp._jspService(NewFile1_jsp.java:139)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:410)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl$OverrideDispatch.dispatch(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:141)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:193)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 28, 2017 4:48:59 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase doPhase
SEVERE: JSF1054: (Phase ID: RENDER_RESPONSE 6, View ID: /NewFile1.jsp) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@19c4105c]
Nov 28, 2017 4:48:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/testJSF] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:113)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperty(UIXComponentELTag.java:135)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.UIXValueTag.setProperties(UIXValueTag.java:77)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.core.output.CoreOutputTextTag.setProperties(CoreOutputTextTag.java:158)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperties(UIXComponentELTag.java:122)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentELTag.createComponent(UIComponentELTag.java:230)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.createChild(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:486)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:670)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.doStartTag(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1142)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.doStartTag(UIXComponentELTag.java:71)
    at org.apache.jsp.NewFile1_jsp._jspx_meth_tr_005foutputText_005f0(NewFile1_jsp.java:211)
    at org.apache.jsp.NewFile1_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(NewFile1_jsp.java:179)
    at org.apache.jsp.NewFile1_jsp._jspService(NewFile1_jsp.java:139)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:410)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl$OverrideDispatch.dispatch(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:141)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:193)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How to fix this for Apache MyFaces Trinidad 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at about 2 years ago. The productive Webserver has been changed from Tomcat7 to Tomcat8 and Trinidad was no longer working. 
I moved the whole Project to jsf 2.2 and trinidad 2.1.1, of which a user solved the Tomcat 8 Problem. It is two years ago, but as far as I know the trinidad community is dead somehow...